# How do I use jQuery sortable to reorder child objects of the sortable parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id='tiles'>

    <div class='slot'>
         <span class='slotNum'>1</span>
         <div class='tile'></div>
    </div>   

    <div class='slot'>
         <span class='slotNum'>2</span>
         <div class='tile'></div>
    </div>    

    <div class='slot'>
        <span class='slotNum'>3</span>
        <div class='tile'></div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

I want to be able to reorder the tiles between the slots. If I start dragging the tile under the #1 to the #2 tile, I want the #2 tile to go under the #1. If you try the JSFiddle, the #2 tile currently just stacks under the reordered tile.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uBFtr/2/)

Comment: This demonstrates sorting the tiles without moving the numbers as well: http://jsfiddle.net/uBFtr/6/. The issue here is your HTML structure, you'll see I've changed it quite a lot. If you want the numbers to move with the tiles then betatester07's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you misconfigured items option - i think that in your example it should be set to .slot, not .tile.

```
$( "#tiles" ).sortable({ 
    items: ".slot",
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uBFtr/5/

By default, items option is set to `> *` selector, which means any child element (not subchild), so  it is not needed to specify it at all in your example.

Comment: I don't want the numbers to move.

Comment: sorry, I didnt realize that you dont want to move the numbers. see Joe's comment